# SAS - Transpose all colums by unique records in each column with counts

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am trying to find efficient, transpose-like code that can convert the Test table below into the Final table. I have code below that works for this example, but for practical purposes, the split data step can produce a very deep table (137 million records in my case, vs 2k as aggregated).

I was hoping there was some Proc or Data step trick I was missing that could skip that intermediate step and be more efficient.

```
Data test;
    Input f1 $ f2 $ f3 $ f4 $ f5 $ f6 $ f7 $ f8 $;

    DataLines;
a c f h k l o q
a c f h k l o q
a c g h k m o q
b c g h k m o q
b d g i k m o r
b d g i k n o r
b e g j k n o s
b e g j k n p s
    ;

Run;

Data final;
    Input field $ values $ records;

    DataLines;
f1 a 3
f1 b 5
f2 c 4
f2 d 2
f2 e 2
f3 f 2
f3 g 6
f4 h 4
f4 i 2
f4 j 2
f5 k 8
f6 l 2
f6 m 3
f6 n 3
f7 o 7
f7 p 1
f8 q 4
f8 r 2
f8 s 2
    ;

Run;


/*Working solution - could it be done more efficiently?*/
Data split;
    Set test;

    Array f{8} f1-f8;
    Do i=1 To 8;
        field = 'f'||PUT(i,best2.);
        values = f{i};
        Output;
    End;

    Drop i f1-f8;
Run;


Proc SQL;
    Create Table final As
    Select
        field
        ,values
        ,COUNT(*) As records Format=comma8.0
    From split
    Group By 1,2
    Order By 1,2
    ;
Quit;
```

Comment: You haven't shown what you want as the final output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Massar:

Frequency counting can be done in a DATA Step hash object that uses the `suminc:` and `keysum:` features:

```
Data have;
    Input f1 $ f2 $ f3 $ f4 $ f5 $ f6 $ f7 $ f8 $;

    DataLines;
a c f h k l o q
a c f h k l o q
a c g h k m o q
b c g h k m o q
b d g i k m o r
b d g i k n o r
b e g j k n o s
b e g j k n p s
    ;

Run;

data want(keep=field value count);
  length field $32 value $8 count 8;
  one = 1;
  call missing (field, value, count);

  declare hash freq(suminc:'one', keysum:'count', ordered:'a', hashexp:20);
  freq.defineKey('field', 'value');
  freq.defineDone();

  do while ( not end );
    set have end=end;
    array f f1-f8;
    do over f; field = vname(f); value=f; freq.ref(); end;
  end;

  declare hiter iter("freq");
  rc = iter.first();
  do while(rc = 0);
    rc = freq.sum(sum: count);
    output;
    rc = iter.next();
  end;

  stop;
run;
```

Comment: Hello, I am not getting this to output to 'want'. I has able to get it to work by adding a hiter with a do while freq.sum(sum: count) and Output. Is this what is missing in your code? You have introduced me to SAS hash tables, so I'm not sure if there is something else that just needs to be tweaked to get your code to write to 'want'.

Comment: Great tweak. I have just learned as well (from tech support) that getting the keysum counts in the output requires a final HITER loop over the hash (when only .REF() is used to obtain the reference sum).

Answer (score 2):

The solution that's likely most time-efficient is to use a summarization procedure.  `PROC TABULATE` seems best suited here.

```
proc tabulate data=test out=test_c;
  class f1-f8;
  tables (f1-f8),n;
run;
data want;
  set test_c;
  array f f1-f8;
  col = cats(of f[*]);
  which_f = whichc(col,of f[*]);
  var = vname(f[which_f]);
  keep col var n;
run;
```

That final datastep is very 'cheap', as it's only done on the summarized dataset so the 2k sized dataset.  As long as you don't have a huge number of columns this should be pretty simple.

If you do have a huge number of columns as well, then the data step based solution that you present above is probably best.  You may be able to speed it up significantly by making the intermediate (split) data step into a view.

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough to do with `PROC SUMMARY`. Use your variable list as `CLASS` variables. You can use the `WAYS` statement to limit it to one-way classification groups. You can use the `CHARTYPE` option to make it easy to transform the results.  You probably will also want to add the `MISSING` option to prevent proc summary eliminating input observations that have a missing value for any of the variables.

```
%let varlist=f1-f8 ;

proc summary data=test chartype missing ;
 class &varlist ;
 ways 1 ;
 output out=result ;
run;

data want ;
  set result ;
  length field $32 value $8 count 8 ;
  array fields &varlist ;
  index=indexc(_type_,'1');
  field=vname(fields(index));
  value=fields(index);
  count=_freq_;
  keep field value count;
run;
```

You might want to reverse the order of the variables so that they come out in the original order.  So use `F8-F1` instead of `F1-F8`.

Note that all of the variables need to be of the same type because of the ARRAY statement in the data step.

Comment: If you do have mixed character and numeric CLASS variables the MLF option on the CLASS statement will convert any numeric class variables to character.
proc summary data=test chartype missing descendtypes;
   class F: / mlf;
   ways 1;
   output out=result;
   run;